# Working with RMW CycloneDDS and SROS2

Tags: ros, dds

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I've been trying to find information on combining SROS2 with CycloneDDS.

I have a full benchmark package with which I test different configurations (RMW, Security, QoS settings, etc.). For the combination where I set the folowing environment variables:

```
RMW_IMPLEMENTATION=rmw_cyclonedds_cpp 
ROS_SECURITY_ENABLE=true 
ROS_SECURITY_STRATEGY=Enforce
```

I get the folowing error message:

```
1602077428.219743 [23]  benchmark: Could not load Authentication library: dds_security_auth: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
1602077428.219749 [23]  benchmark: Could not load Authentication plugin.
1602077428.219751 [23]  benchmark: Could not load security
[ERROR] [1602077428.220364595] [rmw_cyclonedds_cpp]: rmw_create_node: failed to create DDS participant

>>> [rcutils|error_handling.c:108] rcutils_set_error_state()
This error state is being overwritten:

  'error not set, at /tmp/binarydeb/ros-foxy-rcl-1.1.7/src/rcl/node.c:276'

with this new error message:

  'rcl node's rmw handle is invalid, at /tmp/binarydeb/ros-foxy-rcl-1.1.7/src/rcl/node.c:428'

rcutils_reset_error() should be called after error handling to avoid this.
<<<
[ERROR] [1602077428.220430161] [rcl]: Failed to fini publisher for node: 1
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'rclcpp::exceptions::RCLError'
  what():  failed to initialize rcl node: rcl node's rmw handle is invalid, at /tmp/binarydeb/ros-foxy-rcl-1.1.7/src/rcl/node.c:428
```

I can't seem to find information if this is supposed to work with the current versions. I don't have any problem for fastdds with and without security and for cyclone without security.

Package versions:

```
ROS2: Foxy
ros-foxy-rmw-cyclonedds-cpp: 0.7.3-1focal.20200911.211813
```

Following the tutorial on https://github.com/ros2/sros2/blob/foxy/SROS2_Linux.md results in the same error.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/363020/working-with-rmw-cyclonedds-and-sros2/) by [elias](https://answers.ros.org/users/53626/elias/) on ROS Answers with karma: 5 on 2020-10-07

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It seems that the Debian Package of CycloneDDS doesn't include security function.

I think there is something wrong (maybe lack of definition for building) while creating CycloneDDS packages for ROS 2.

However, you can workaround this by building Cyclone DDS from source code.

I've tried to use source code build instead and it works well with SROS.

---

Originally posted by [evshary](https://answers.ros.org/users/57699/evshary/) with karma: 16 on 2020-10-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [elias](https://answers.ros.org/users/53626/elias/) on 2020-10-22**:
a build of the release branch 0.7.x did the trick. thanks